# MS-CHAPv2 Auth protocol downgrade

Tags: authentication, man-in-the-middle, attacks

I'm researching about PPP (Point to Point protocol) and it's security aspects.
While exploring PPP Authentication I've noticed possibility for security downgrade attack. Generally authentication procedure looks as follows:

[image: Wireshark PPP caputre]

1. Client starts PPP discovery
   and begins auth procedure
   with server
2. Both server and client exchanges configuration parameters
3. Server sends client a challenge
4. Client responds
5. Server sends client a result (Success or PADT)

What really caught my attention was not checking server authenticity in any of steps. Mainly in configuration step which dictates which authentication protocol should be used.

[image: Wireshark server conf]

Later then client send acknowledgment. Does this mean that a potential attacker could downgrade authentication security by sending Configuration Request faster than server?
For example selecting PAP which would make client send password in cleartext. There is high chance that I missed something and I'm horribly incorrect but that looks like it.

Comment: Note that MS-CHAP is not substantially more secure than a plaintext password.  The cost to crack the underlying algorithms is about USD 20.

Comment: @bk2204 That is true, the underlying DES encryption is relatively easy to crack because of 2^56 bit key space (Which is substantially lower than any modern encryption). But even this weak encryption can pose challenge to crack for PC (Calculated it would take about 40ish days on my machine). Of course there are specialized machines that can crack such key in less than several hours but still that is *some* protection. In my later testing I've discovered my hypnosis to be true which gives a password and not key and requires little to none computing power with very few active steps as MITM.